# Spark StringIndexer consistent output value for given input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Is it possible to use Spark's StringIndexer to consistently return the same output for a given input (I.e a column labelled 'Apple' will always output say '56.0')

The use case is when indexing multiple DataFrames and not all the inputs are inclusive in both but, you want to ensure ones which are, are converted to the same indexed value.

I'm trying to avoid my own String => Number mapping and wondered if StringIndexer could do this.

Answer (score 0):

After looking some more I came across this similar post:
[Spark ML StringIndexer Different Labels Training/Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578936/spark-ml-stringindexer-different-labels-training-testing/36580672)

If you *save* the StringIndexerModel used firstly and reuse it for transformation of any further DataFrames you'll get the same outputs.

I've flagged this post as a duplicate.